# Problems with SQL Server 2008 - "The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 62, which had ..."

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection

I'm having problems with my SQL Server 2008 installation (10.0.2531.0 - SP1 installed). It works as a database server for small hosting environment (about 500 sites).

I'm getting errors like this:

> The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 62, which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 29. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.

in Windows event log and when I run this:

```
SELECT  *  FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE object_name = 'SQLServer:General Statistics'
```

I see that one of counters looks a little odd:

```
Logins/sec                   429
Connection Reset/sec         163459
Logouts/sec                  399
User Connections             30
Logical Connections          33
```

any ideas how to check what is causing this problem?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Our whole team is getting this error on one section of our code, were you able to find out any more info?

Cheers

Comment: This ended up being a malformed date value of a parameter we were passing in.  Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Possibly related: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2543687/EN-US

Answer (score 3):

[There is an MSDN blog post about how to work with this error.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/08/03/how-it-works-error-18056-the-client-was-unable-to-reuse-a-session-with-spid-which-had-been-reset-for-connection-pooling.aspx)  It's not very good, but it does give some pointers as to how you can interpret the error code (failure ID).

Typically what happens is there is some expensive work to do while reinitializing the connection (such as access control and validation).  This creates a potential race condition.  While the server is doing this work, the client may time out and close the connection or do something else, creating an exception.  Corrupt input, as campo mentioned in his comment, could well exacerbate that.

This isn't the only possible cause of the error; anything that causes an exception during the session reinitialization might cause this.  The name of the error code is `RedoLoginException`.